# Multiple SELECT Statement using One Table of SQL

Tags: sql, multiple-select

Hope u all fine.
Actually I'm working on a Project and need to calculate daily TOTAL_SALE and TOTAL_CASH and TOTAL_CREDIT ....
Following is my Query but my Query Gives Overall SUM of Payments in TOTAL_CASH and in TOTAL_CREDIT as it has to be like this ..

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| TOTAL_SALE | TOTAL_CASH | TOTAL_CREDIT |
+------------+------------+--------------+
|       1000 |        250 |          750 |
+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Following is my SQL Query :-

```
SELECT

 sss.creation_date , SUM(sss.payment_due) as 'Total Sale', 
 (SELECT SUM(s.payment_due) FROM sale s WHERE s.payment_method LIKE '%Cash_%' AND s.shop='10' 
  AND s.DateNum >='20181201000000' AND s.DateNum <='20181231235959' GROUP BY s.creation_date)as 'Total Cash' , 

  (SELECT SUM(ss.payment_due) FROM sale ss WHERE ss.payment_method LIKE '%cCredit_%' AND ss.shop='10' 
  AND ss.DateNum >='20181201000000' AND ss.DateNum <='20181231235959' GROUP BY ss.creation_date)as 'Total Credit' , 

 SUM(discount) as 'Total Discount' , SUM(number_of_item_purchased) as 'Total Sold'

 FROM Sale sss

 WHERE sss.shop='10' AND sss.DateNum >='20181201000000' AND sss.DateNum <='20181231235959'

 GROUP BY sss.creation_date
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking can you add some relative data and expected resultset. Also you can simplify current qury using `CASE`

Comment: look sir I have an sale table where daily sales record save
but the schema of sql is like total sale column has the value (20) and payment method is 'cash'
and next sale on same day is of 40 and payment method is 'Credit'
Now how to specify as Total sale is of 80 and Cash is of 20 and Credit if of 60
Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
 SUM(payment_due) as 'Total Sale', 
 SUM(case when payment_method LIKE '%Cash_%' then s.payment_due end) as 'Total Cash' , 
 SUM(case when payment_method LIKE '%cCredit_%' then payment_due end) as 'Total Credit', 
 SUM(discount) as 'Total Discount' , 
 SUM(number_of_item_purchased) as 'Total Sold'
 FROM Sale 
 WHERE shop='10' AND DateNum >='20181201000000' AND DateNum <='20181231235959'
```

Comment: Sir u are like an angel for me I was searching and searching for this since last night 
But u really owe me ....

Comment: U really owe me SIR